# Trying to print the position of the element on the linked list, it seems to just print PS

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list

trying to print the position of an element on the linked list via using a counter variable hop and returning it on success.

```
class Node_or_Element:

    def __init__(self,data): # Function to initialize the element's or the nodes
        self.data=data
        self.next=None

class Linked_list:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head=None
    
    def print_list(self):
        temp=self.head
        while(temp):
            print(temp.data)
            temp=temp.next
    
    def pos(self,data):
        curr=self.head
        while(curr==None):
            hop=0
            if(curr.data!=data):
                curr=curr.next
                hop+=1
            elif(curr.data==data):
                print(hop)
                
# Start with the empty list
llist = Linked_list()
llist.head = Node_or_Element(1)
second = Node_or_Element(2)
third = Node_or_Element(3)
  
llist.head.next = second  # Link first node with second
second.next = third # Link second node with the third node
third.next=None
  
llist.print_list()

llist.pos(2)
```

Expected output:

```
1
2
3
1
```

resulting output:

```
1
2
3
```

PS idk why it's printing PS

Comment: unable to reproduce https://www.online-python.com/MJ82nUKrZs

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The condition `while(curr==None):` is backwards, it should be `while curr is not None:`

Answer (score 1):

Yours `pos` function is the problem. You see, there is `while(curr==None)` but that never happens since `curr=self.head`...

I would advice you something like this:

```
def pos(self, l_data):
   curr = self.head
   index = 0

   while(True):
      if curr.data == l_data:
         return index
      elif curr.next != None:
         curr = curr.next
         index += 1
      else:
         return -1
```

EDIT: Also in your `pos` function there is line `hop=0` which is **inside the `while` so it will always be 0 every iteration**!